# All processor think they are the root when I compile with mpifort

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have code that compiles and runs fine with mpif90 and mpiifort, however when I compile it with mpifort all processors will have rank 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That typically occurs when you mix two MPI implementations.

For example, `mpif90` and `mpirun` might be from MPICH (or its derivative) but `mpifort` is provided by Open MPI (or its derivative).

I recommend you double check that:

- `which mpif90`
- `which mpifort`
- `which mpirun`

and compare the outputs of `ldd a.out` when compiled with `mpif90` vs `mpifort`.